# Предназначение папки resources

Tags: java, resources

Вечер добрый всем.
Возник вопрос кое-какой. Для чего нужна папка "resources"?
У знакомого спрашивали на собеседовании и что-то он поплыл и мне стало интересно, а точнее вопрос звучал так:

> Папка «Resources» где должна находиться и когда ее нужно удалять?

Answer (score -1):

По хорошему, папка resources должна находиться рядом с исходными кодами Java. А по факту там где её положишь. Нужна для того что бы (ты не поверишь) хранить ресурсы программы. Статические файлы, картинки, темплейты, и прочую лабудень что не является исходным кодом Java. Но так или иначе необходимы в проекте.

**Пример папки res в Андроид проекте  (src\res)**

[image: Пример папки res в Андроид проекте]

**Пример папки res в Java/Scala проекте (src\main\resources)**

[image: Пример папки res в Java/Scala проекте]

Comment: Ну вот для своих проектов я туда кидал чисто изображения, поэтому как-то заблудился в этом вопросе.

Comment: И удалять её следует, если нету ресурсов в твоем проекте, верно?

Comment: @AlexanderByzov **Нет, не верно!** Там хранятся манифесты которые так или иначе попадают в jar / war которые так или иначе нужны в проекте! Если ты конечно не собираешься весь проект деплоить как набор .class файлов. Если ты хочешь все разложить без упаковки голыми скомпилированными .class файлами, то да можно удалять.